# calendarview highlights wrong week

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have a CalendarView in my app, when the user selects a date by touching that date in the monthview, the correct date is selected (verified by adding debug statements in the code), but the week before is highlighted, so it looks as if the wrong date is selected.

I have found a work-around: if I set 'firstDayInWeek' to 1 the problem is solved, but by default the firstDayInweek is 2 (monday), and then this problem occurs.

Thank you very much!

Samsung S4 with API 21

Comment: hi did you get any solution ? Please share if so.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue as you, using a Samsung S5 running API 21.

There are two workarounds that I have found, none of them is a good experience for our users :(

1. Force first day of the week to Sunday

```
    calendarView.setFirstDayOfTheWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

2. Set a minimum and a maximum date for the calendar (be careful because not all of the dates work here). I was able to make it work properly setting a minimum date 2 months before the current date and maximum date 2 years after the current date. You can play with these values and find a good compromise between the limits and your user experience.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 2);
    calendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 2);
    calendarView.setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Unfortunately, this is the only way I could fix this issue, I hope it is useful for you.