# Samsung S5 CalendarView shows wrong day

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, calendarview

In my app i use CalendarView to pick periods.  Problem that CalendaView shows selected day wrong, for example in screen it shows |27| but actually day is |4|.

Problem shows only on Samsung S5, but on SonyXperie, Nexus everything normal.
I can't test all phones, but it's very strange for me..

Any ideas how i can avoid it?[sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuucO.png)

Comment: Probably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174539/calendarview-highlights-wrong-week) will help you.

Comment: Yes.. I was see that answer, but seems not undestens in first.. now i try and it works..!!